# Click event gets removed when clicking button - Vue / Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a dialog with Vuetify. The button should open a dialog and that's basically that. It's also possible to close the dialog after finishing business. When closing the dialog in development, we can just open the dialog again. But in production environment, we cannot open the dialog more than once.

I have found the cause, or at least what I believe to be the cause of this; The click event gets removed from the DOM/Window when clicking the button the first time - ONLY in production.

This is not happening in development environment.

I had an idea, that some of the old code in our project is doing something, but can't seem to find the culprit...

So I wanted to hear you out, if this has ever happened to anyone before? :)

Our tech is:

- Vue 2
- Vuetify 2.7
- some old jQuery

Let me know if you need some more code.

Modal container:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-tooltip left>
      <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          class="o-page-sidebar__button create-project__button"
          color="#009688"
          dark
          depressed
          tile
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
          @click="triggerModal(undefined)"
        >
          <v-icon size="16">
            fal fa-clipboard-list
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>{{ translations.title }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>

    <CreateProjectModal
      v-if="showModal"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      v-model="showModal"
      :translations="translations"
      @hasEditedProject="handleHasEditedProject"
      @hasCreatedProject="handleHasCreatedProject"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    triggerModal(eventObject) {
      if (eventObject == undefined) {
        eventObject = {};
      }

      const localStorageValue = localStorage.useNewCreateProjectDialog != undefined ? localStorage.useNewCreateProjectDialog == 'true' : true;

      const openRequest = {
        Type: eventObject.type,
        ProjectID: eventObject.projectID,
        OfferID: eventObject.offerID,
        DebtorID: eventObject.debtorID,
        FitterID: eventObject.fitterID,
        ManagerID: eventObject.managerID,
        PlanningStartDate: eventObject.planningStartDate,
        PlanningEndDate: eventObject.planningEndDate
      };

      this.notification.show = false;

      if (localStorageValue) {
        const type = eventObject.type ? eventObject.type : 'CreateProject';

        openRequest.Type = this.openProjectDialogEnum.find(x => x.Name == type)?.Name;

        this.$store.dispatch('setOpenRequest', openRequest);

        this.$store.dispatch('setHasInitializedFields', {
          'MainProjectID': false,
          'OfferID': false,
          'ProjectDebtorID': openRequest.Type != 'EditProject',
          'ProjectGroupID': openRequest.Type != 'EditProject'
        });

        this.showModal = true;
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Modal component:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-model="show"
    :class="{ 'new-create-project' : show }"
    fullscreen
    :retain-focus="false"
    hide-overlay
    persistent
    no-click-animation
    height="100vh"
    transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
    @keydown.esc="confirmClose"
  >
    {{ ... }}
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  computed: {
    show: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        if (!value) {
          this.$store.dispatch('setNotifications', []);
          this.$store.dispatch('setSelectedDebtor', null);
          this.$store.dispatch('emptyErrors');
        }

        this.$store.dispatch('resetProjectData');
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

EDIT:
After further inspection it seems that the entire component is re-rendered when opening the dialog.

EDIT: If I remove all the components loaded in dialog's tabs the error, is not happening. Maybe I am loading these wrong. Here is how I am doing it, let me know what's wrong here:

```
<v-tabs
          ref="tabs"
          v-model="currentTab"
          v-shortkey.once="{save: ['ctrl', 'q'], saveAndPrint: ['alt', 'q'], tabRight: ['alt', 'arrowright'], tabLeft: ['alt', 'arrowleft']}"
          grow
          @shortkey.native="handleShortcuts"
        >
          <v-tab
            v-for="(tab, i) in mappedTabs"
            :key="i"
            :disabled="(tab.canDisable && !enableTabs) || tab.disabled"
          >
            <v-icon left>
              {{ tab.icon }}
            </v-icon>
            {{ tab.name }}
            <v-icon
              v-if="tab.hasErrors"
              size="14"
              color="error"
              class="ml-2"
            >
             fa fa-exclamation-triangle
            </v-icon>
          </v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
      </v-card-text>

      <v-tabs-items
        v-model="currentTab"
        class="grow d-grid"
      >
        <v-card-text class="fill-height">
          <v-tab-item
            v-for="(tab, i) in mappedTabs"
            :key="`${i}-item`"
            class="fill-height"
          >
            <component
              :is="tab.component"
              :is-active="currentTab === i"
              v-bind="$attrs"
              from-create-project
              class="create-project__form"
              @show-association="showAssociation"
              @set-contact-person="setContactPerson"
              @set-work-address="setWorkAddress"
            />
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-tabs-items>
```

This is an example of a tab that I am looping over:

```
 {
   name: this.translations.tabProjectInformation,
   hasErrors: this.$store.getters.hasProjectInformationErrors,
   icon: 'fal fa-clipboard-list',
   component: 'ProjectInformation'
 },
```

Comment: Have you checked the [Vue devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) extension for Chrome? Does the browser console output anything unusual? Click handlers won't suddenly be removed for no reason between a dev and production build. Why do you supply the eventObject as undefined? Why not just create a separate variable? This way you could debug the real event object.

Comment: Are you sure the click hanlder is removed? Could you log on the first line of your handler to check if it is really not firing?

Comment: @PeterKrebs I have checked Vue devtools and Chrome console. Nothing gets output which is also why I think this is very weird behaviour..

You are right, that's a good idea, can't believe I didn't think about that myself, will do.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I've tried logging the output to the console, and nothing gets logged.

I can even see in the event listener overview in Chrom devtools that the event gets removed 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different stuff I finally found a solution that worked for me. For some reason loading the components asynchronous caused the dialog to re-render. I don't have the knowledge to understand why this happens, so if someone knows, please enlighten me :D

This fixed my production:

From this

```
components: {
    ProjectInformation: () => import('./components/ProjectInformation.vue'),
    WorksheetsTab: () => import('./components/WorksheetsTab.vue'),
    BudgetTab: () => import('./components/BudgetTab.vue'),
    QualityAssurance: () => import('./components/QualityAssurance.vue'),
    Subscription: () => import('@/components/Shared/Dialogs/Subscription/components/Subscription.vue'),
    Documentation: () => import('./components/Documentation.vue'),
    ProjectAgreementTab: () => import('./components/ProjectAgreementTab.vue')
  },
```

To this

```
import WorksheetsTab from './components/WorksheetsTab';
import BudgetTab from './components/BudgetTab';
import QualityAssurance from './components/QualityAssurance';
import Subscription from '@/components/Shared/Dialogs/Subscription/components/Subscription';
import Documentation from './components/Documentation';
import ProjectAgreementTab from './components/ProjectAgreementTab';
```